# How to show date only if there is date and time?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

While displaying the view. It shows `order_date` and `expected_date` in DateTime format.

It shows `order_date` as `8/19/2017 12:00:00 AM` and `expected_date` as `8/22/2017 12:00:00 AM`. In SQL Server both `order_date` and `expected_date` have the `Date` datatype.

What should I do to only show the date?

```
 <table>
    @{
    int cann = ((DataTable)ViewBag.orderdata).Rows.Count;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewBag.orderdata;
    for (int i = 0; i < cann; i++)
    {
    <tr>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["order_id"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["customer_name"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["Customer_address"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["customer_phone"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["order_date"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["expected_date"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["total_amount"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["advance_amount"]</td>
    <td>@dt.Rows[i]["due_amount"]</td>
    <td><a href="/NewOrder/EditOrder?id=@dt.Rows[i]["order_id"]" 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></a>|<a href="/NewOrder/DeleteOrder?
    id=@dt.Rows[i]["order_id"]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>|<a 
    href="/NewOrder/DetailsData?id=@dt.Rows[i]["order_id"]" class="glyphicon 
    glyphicon-dashboard"></a></td>

    </tr>
    }
    }
    </table>
```

In Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ViewOrder()
        {
            SqlQuery.Order see = new SqlQuery.Order();
            DataTable view = see.ViewOrder();
            ViewBag.orderdata = view;
            return View();
        }`
```

Sql Query:

```
 public DataTable ViewOrder()
    {
        string sql = "select * from ProductOrder";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter view = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        view.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use Convert(Date,"YourDateColumn") in SQL. If you want in specific format i.e. dd/MM/YYYY you can try Convert(varchar,GETDATE(),103)

Answer (score 2):

Dude, first of all it is not a good practice exposing your id in view, please read layered architecture. read about Data Layer responsibility.
but the answer of your question is

```
@DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["order_date"]).ToString("yy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: Thanks. But can't understand what you are saying about "exposing your id in view"

Comment: It doesn't work  <td>@DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["order_date"]).ToShortDateString()</td>

Comment: i have fix my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In Sql Sever:
select format(expected_date,'dd-MM-yyyy'),format(order_date,'dd-MM-yyyy') from ProductOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CAST` function to convert from datetime to date, as below:

```
sql = "select order_id, customer_name, Customer_address, customer_phone,
CAST(order_date as date) as order_date, CAST(expected_date as date) as expected_date,
total_amount, advance_amount, due_amount from ProductOrder"
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server :

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), expected_date, 103) AS expected_date,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), order_date, 103) AS order_date from ProductOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

@dt.Rows[i]["order_date"].Date.ToString("d")